# URI issue with ftp server

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, uri

I am having trouble to access a FTP server via C# because of not finding the right URI.
The ftp server can be found using ftp.xxx.com - thus ftp ftp.xxx.com works from the command line, ftp ftp://ftp.xxx.com yields unknown host via the command line. The same happens then when using

```
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(Settings.Default.FtpServer, UriKind.Absolute));
```

inside my C# program
What am I doing wrong/how do I need to determine the URI?

Comment: What is the actual value of `Settings.Default.FtpServer`?

Comment: The accepted answer got deleted. The following solution from MSDN helped."The URI may be relative or absolute. If the URI is of the form "ftp://contoso.com/%2fpath" (%2f is an escaped '/'), then the URI is absolute, and the current directory is /path. If, however, the URI is of the form "ftp://contoso.com/path", first the .NET Framework logs into the FTP server (using the user name and password set by the Credentials property), then the current directory is set to <UserLoginDirectory>/path."

Answer (score 0):

Which WebRequestMethod do you set? If its set to download a file, it might fail because your URI is not pointing to a file but to the root directory of the server.
Im not sure if its the point can't test it myself but looks logically to me.

edit:
Default Method is DownloadFile (looked up with reflector)

Comment: WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile is my method, but the crash happens right at the constructor. Could it be that I need to add a routing for the URI?

Answer (score -1):

finalUri = ftp://11.11.11.11/ + Uri.EscapeDataString(folder) + / + Uri.EscapeDataString(folder) ... / + Uri.EscapeDataString(filename)

Answer (score -1):

Try It

```
FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + xx.xx.xx.xx + "/" + FileName));
```